# How do you send bulk inserts with no ids to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the bulk inset api for elastic search. I would like to insert documents with auto generated IDs but I'm just getting errors no matter what i try.

Here are a few example efforts:

```
http://localhost:9200/_bulk
{"create": {"_index": "test", "_type": "_doc"} }
{"user": "kimchy", "post_date": "2002-11-15T14:12:12", "message": "trying out Elasticsearch"}
```

Both put and post give the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: an id must be provided if version type or value are set;"
      }
    ],
    "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: an id must be provided if version type or value are set;"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

If i remove _type _doc i get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;2: an id is required for a CREATE operation;3: an id must be provided if version type or value are set;"
      }
    ],
    "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;2: an id is required for a CREATE operation;3: an id must be provided if version type or value are set;"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I'm using elastic search 6.4.2 via docker

```
~ docker images
REPOSITORY       TAG       IMAGE ID      CREATED      SIZE
elasticsearch    6.4.2     e47ebd7ec3ee  7 weeks ago  828MB
```

Currently sending requests via postman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want automatic id creation simply use `index` instead of `create`:

```
change this
    |
    v
{"index": {"_index": "test", "_type": "_doc"} }
{"user": "kimchy", "post_date": "2002-11-15T14:12:12", "message": "trying out Elasticsearch"}
```